# Can you subtotal rows and/or columns in a pivot table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot, subtotal

I have a set of queries that outputs a pivot table.  Is it possible to obtain row and/or column subtotals for a pivot table ?

My table I am selecting from looks like this

```
    Site     FormID   Present
    Site 1   Form A      Yes
    Site 1   Form B      Yes
    Site 1   Form D      Yes
```

etc...

My pivot table query is this

```
   SELECT *
   FROM (SELECT Site, COUNT(FormID) AS NumberOfForms,FormID
         FROM @CRFCount WHERE Present='Yes'
         GROUP BY Site, FormID) d
   PIVOT
   (SUM(NumberOfForms)
   FOR [Site] IN ([Site 1], [Site 2], [Site 3])
   )  AS p;
```

But I really want it to result in this (which of course it does not total for me)

```
    FormID  Site 1  Site 2  Site 3  Total
    Form A      8      8      15    31
    Form B     14      4    NULL    18
    Form C     14   NULL    NULL    14
    Form D     15      3      16    34
    Form E     12      4    NULL    16
    Form F     14      5       5    24
    Form G     14      8       6    28
    Form H     22     10      15    47
    Form I     15     10      16    41
    Form J     15      5      16    36
    Total     143     57      89   289
```

Thanks for your assistance !

-Don

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
;WITH C as
(
  SELECT FormID,
         [Site 1],
         [Site 2],
         [Site 3],
         (SELECT SUM(S)
          FROM (VALUES([Site 1]),
                      ([Site 2]),
                      ([Site 3])) AS T(S)) as Total
   FROM (SELECT Site, COUNT(FormID) AS NumberOfForms,FormID
         FROM @CRFCount WHERE Present='Yes'
         GROUP BY Site, FormID) d
   PIVOT
   (SUM(NumberOfForms)
   FOR [Site] IN ([Site 1], [Site 2], [Site 3])
   )  AS p
)
SELECT *
FROM
  (
    SELECT FormID,
           [Site 1],
           [Site 2],
           [Site 3],
           Total
    FROM C
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Total',
           SUM([Site 1]),
           SUM([Site 2]),
           SUM([Site 3]),
           SUM(Total)
    FROM C
  ) AS T
ORDER BY CASE WHEN FormID = 'Total' THEN 1 END
```

**Note:** If you are using SQL Server 2005 you need to change this:

```
 (SELECT SUM(S)
  FROM (VALUES([Site 1]),
              ([Site 2]),
              ([Site 3])) AS T(S)) as Total
```

to

```
 (SELECT SUM(S)
  FROM (SELECT [Site 1] UNION ALL
        SELECT [Site 2] UNION ALL
        SELECT [Site 3]) AS T(S)) as Total
```

Try on [SE Data](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/116000/)

Answer (score 2):

Try this (not tested):

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT
        Site = case when grouping(Site)=1 then 'All' else Site end,
        FormID = case when grouping(FormID)=1 then 'All' else cast(FormID as varchar(100)) end,
        measure = count(NumberOfForms)
    FROM @CRFCount 
       -- chose below
       GROUP BY Site, FormID with cube --(ms sql 2005)
       --group by grouping sets(Site, FormID, (Site, FormID), ()) --(ms sql 2008)
) AS BOM
PIVOT  (max(measure) FOR [Site] IN ([Site 1], [Site 2], [Site 3], [All]))
as pv
```

Comment: In SQL Server 2008 it could be just `GROUP BY CUBE (Site, FormID)`, although your `GROUPING SETS ()` equivalent of `CUBE ()` is correct too.

Answer (score 0):

**SAMPLE TABLE**

```
SELECT * INTO #TEMP 
FROM
(
    SELECT 'Site 1' [Site],   'Form A' [FormID],      'Yes' Present
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Site 1',   'Form B',      'Yes'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Site 1',   'Form C',      'Yes'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Site 1',   'Form B',      'NO'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Site 1',   'Form C',      'NO'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Site 2',   'Form A',      'Yes'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Site 2',   'Form A',      'Yes'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Site 2',   'Form B',      'Yes'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Site 2',   'Form B',      'NO'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Site 2',   'Form C',      'Yes'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Site 3',   'Form B',      'Yes'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Site 3',   'Form A',      'Yes'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Site 3',   'Form C',      'Yes'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Site 3',   'Form A',      'Yes'
)TAB
```

**1. Row and Column Total**

```
-- Get the columns for dynamic pivot
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR (MAX)

SELECT @cols = COALESCE (@cols + ',[' + [Site] + ']', '[' + [Site] + ']')
               FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [Site] FROM  #TEMP WHERE Present='YES') PV 
               ORDER BY [Site] 
-- Since we need Total in last column, we append it at last
SELECT @cols += ',[Total]'
```

You can use `CUBE` to get the row and column total on pivoting. More about `CUBE` [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522495%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @query = 'SELECT FORMID,' + @cols + ' FROM 
             (
                 SELECT 
                 ISNULL([SITE],''Total'')[SITE], 
                 SUM(CNT)CNT , 
                 ISNULL(FORMID,''Total'')FORMID              
                 FROM 
                 (
                    SELECT DISTINCT [SITE],FORMID,
                    COUNT(FORMID) OVER(PARTITION BY [SITE],FORMID) CNT
                    FROM #TEMP
                    WHERE PRESENT=''YES''
                 )TAB
                 GROUP BY [SITE],FORMID
                 WITH CUBE
             ) x
             PIVOT 
             (
                 MIN(CNT)
                 FOR [SITE] IN (' + @cols + ')
            ) p
            ORDER BY CASE WHEN (FORMID=''Total'') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,FORMID' 

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query
```

**2. Row Total only**

You can use `ROLLUP` to get the row total.

```
-- Get the columns for dynamic pivot
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR (MAX)

SELECT @cols = COALESCE (@cols + ',[' + [Site] + ']', '[' + [Site] + ']')
               FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [Site] FROM  #TEMP WHERE Present='YES') PV 
               ORDER BY [Site] 



DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @query = 'SELECT FORMID,' + @cols + ' FROM 
             (
                 SELECT 
                 ISNULL([SITE],''Total'')[SITE], 
                 SUM(CNT)CNT , 
                 ISNULL(FORMID,''Total'')FORMID              
                 FROM 
                 (
                    SELECT DISTINCT [SITE],FORMID,
                    COUNT(FORMID) OVER(PARTITION BY [SITE],FORMID) CNT
                    FROM #TEMP
                    WHERE PRESENT=''YES''
                 )TAB
                 GROUP BY [SITE],FORMID
                 WITH ROLLUP
             ) x
             PIVOT 
             (
                 MIN(CNT)
                 FOR [SITE] IN (' + @cols + ')
            ) p
            ORDER BY CASE WHEN (FORMID=''Total'') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,FORMID' 

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query
```

**3. Column Total only**

Change `GROUP BY [SITE],FORMID` to `GROUP BY FORMID,[SITE]`

```
-- Get the columns for dynamic pivot
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR (MAX)

SELECT @cols = COALESCE (@cols + ',[' + [Site] + ']', '[' + [Site] + ']')
               FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [Site] FROM  #TEMP WHERE Present='YES') PV 
               ORDER BY [Site] 

 --Since we need Total in last column, we append it at last
SELECT @cols += ',[Total]'


DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @query = 'SELECT FORMID,' + @cols + ' FROM 
             (
                 SELECT 
                 ISNULL([SITE],''Total'')[SITE], 
                 SUM(CNT)CNT , 
                 ISNULL(FORMID,''Total'')FORMID              
                 FROM 
                 (
                    SELECT DISTINCT [SITE],FORMID,
                    COUNT(FORMID) OVER(PARTITION BY [SITE],FORMID) CNT
                    FROM #TEMP
                    WHERE PRESENT=''YES''
                 )TAB
                 GROUP BY FORMID,[SITE]
                 WITH ROLLUP
             ) x
             PIVOT 
             (
                 MIN(CNT)
                 FOR [SITE] IN (' + @cols + ')
            ) p
            WHERE FORMID <> ''Total''
            ORDER BY FORMID' 

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query
```

Now, if you want to replace null with zero, you can use the below code before dynamic pivot.

```
DECLARE @NulltoZeroCols NVARCHAR (MAX)

SELECT @NullToZeroCols = SUBSTRING((SELECT ',ISNULL(['+[Site]+'],0) AS ['+[Site]+']' 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [Site] FROM #TEMP)TAB  
ORDER BY [Site] FOR XML PATH('')),2,8000) 

SELECT @NullToZeroCols += ',ISNULL([Total],0) AS [Total]'
```

And in the out most query of dynamic pivot, replace `@cols` variable with `@NullToZeroCols`