# SQL pivot table with column and row totals

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, pivot-table

In am trying to add row and column totals to this pivot table

```
      create table test4(city nvarchar(10), race nvarchar(30), sex nvarchar(10), age int)
            insert into test4 values ('Austin',  'African-American', 'male', 21)
            insert into test4 values ('Austin',  'Asian', 'female', 22)
            insert into test4 values ('Austin',  'Caucasian', 'male', 23)
            insert into test4 values ('Austin',  'Hispanic', 'female', 24)
            insert into test4 values ('Austin',  'African-American', 'Unknown', 25)
            insert into test4 values ('Austin',  'Asian', 'male', 26)
            insert into test4 values ('Austin',  'Caucasian', 'female', 27)
            insert into test4 values ('Austin',  'Hispanic', 'Unknown', 28)
            insert into test4 values ('Austin',  'Asian', 'male', 29)
            insert into test4 values ('Austin',  'Caucasian', 'female', 31)
            insert into test4 values ('Dallas',  'Hispanic', 'Unknown', 32)
            insert into test4 values ('Dallas',  'African-American', 'male', 33)
            insert into test4 values ('Dallas',  'Asian', 'female', 34)
            insert into test4 values ('Dallas',  'Caucasian', 'Unknown', 35)
            insert into test4 values ('Dallas',  'Hispanic', 'male', 500)
            insert into test4 values ('Dallas',  'African-American', 'female', 36)
            insert into test4 values ('Dallas',  'Asian', 'Unknown', 37)
            insert into test4 values ('Dallas',  'Caucasian', 'male', 38)
            insert into test4 values ('Dallas',  'Hispanic', 'female', 39)
            insert into test4 values ('Dallas',  'African-American', 'Unknown', 41)
            insert into test4 values ('Houston',  'Asian', 'male', 42)
            insert into test4 values ('Houston',  'Caucasian', 'female', 43)
            insert into test4 values ('Houston',  'Hispanic', 'Unknown', 44)
            insert into test4 values ('Houston',  'African-American', 'male', 45)
            insert into test4 values ('Houston',  'Asian', 'female', 46)
            insert into test4 values ('Houston',  'Caucasian', 'Unknown', 47)
            insert into test4 values ('Houston',  'Hispanic', 'male', 48)
            insert into test4 values ('Houston',  'African-American', 'female', 49)
            insert into test4 values ('Houston',  'Asian', 'Unknown', 51)
            insert into test4 values ('Houston',  'Caucasian', 'male', 52);

            WITH T AS (
            SELECT 
                  A.city as city, A.sex as sex,  
                  CASE
                        WHEN A.age BETWEEN 20 AND 30 THEN '20-30_' + race
                        WHEN A.age BETWEEN 31 AND 40 THEN '31-40_' + race
                        WHEN A.age BETWEEN 41 AND 50 THEN '41-50_' + race
                   END AS age_range_race
           FROM test4 AS A
           )
           SELECT  *
           FROM T
           PIVOT( COUNT(age_range_race) FOR age_range_race
               IN(
                  [20-30_African-American], 
                  [20-30_Asian], 
                  [20-30_Caucasian], 
                  [20-30_Hispanic],
                  [31-40_African-American], 
                  [31-40_Asian], 
                  [31-40_Caucasian], 
                  [31-40_Hispanic],
                  [41-50_African-American], 
                  [41-50_Asian], 
                  [41-50_Caucasian], 
                  [41-50_Hispanic]
                 )
            ) AS P
```

I am trying to achieve this result

[image: 1]

The only examples I can find on Google are stored procedures written for SQL 2000. Please help! Thanks in advance

Comment: Your script is working, right?

Comment: yes, I am just trying to create totals.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you subtotal rows and/or columns in a pivot table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7925748/can-you-subtotal-rows-and-or-columns-in-a-pivot-table)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here you try.

```
WITH T AS (
            SELECT 
                  A.city as city, A.sex as sex,  
                  CASE
                        WHEN A.age BETWEEN 20 AND 30 THEN '20-30_' + race
                        WHEN A.age BETWEEN 31 AND 40 THEN '31-40_' + race
                        WHEN A.age BETWEEN 41 AND 50 THEN '41-50_' + race
                   END AS age_range_race
           FROM #test4 AS A
           )


SELECT  *, ([20-30_African-American] + [20-30_Asian] + [20-30_Caucasian]+ [20-30_Hispanic]+ [31-40_African-American]+ [31-40_Asian]+ [31-40_Caucasian]+ [31-40_Hispanic]+[41-50_African-American]+ [41-50_Asian]+ [41-50_Caucasian]+ [41-50_Hispanic]) Total
into #tmp_result
FROM T
PIVOT( COUNT(age_range_race) FOR age_range_race
   IN(
      [20-30_African-American], 
      [20-30_Asian], 
      [20-30_Caucasian], 
      [20-30_Hispanic],
      [31-40_African-American], 
      [31-40_Asian], 
      [31-40_Caucasian], 
      [31-40_Hispanic],
      [41-50_African-American], 
      [41-50_Asian], 
      [41-50_Caucasian], 
      [41-50_Hispanic]
     )
) AS P

select * 
from #tmp_result
union all
select 'Grand Total','',SUM([20-30_African-American]), SUM([20-30_Asian]), SUM([20-30_Caucasian]), SUM([20-30_Hispanic]),SUM([31-40_African-American]), SUM([31-40_Asian]), SUM([31-40_Caucasian]), SUM([31-40_Hispanic]),SUM([41-50_African-American]), SUM([41-50_Asian]), SUM([41-50_Caucasian]),SUM([41-50_Hispanic]), sum(Total)
from #tmp_result
```

Comment: its really simple and good, but can we modify it parametric? for able to use with dynamic columns.

Answer (score 2):

Please try as follow..

```
WITH T AS (
            SELECT 
                  A.city as city, A.sex as sex,  
                  CASE
                        WHEN A.age BETWEEN 20 AND 30 THEN '20-30_' + race
                        WHEN A.age BETWEEN 31 AND 40 THEN '31-40_' + race
                        WHEN A.age BETWEEN 41 AND 50 THEN '41-50_' + race
                   END AS age_range_race
           FROM #test4 AS A
           )


SELECT  *, ([20-30_African-American] + [20-30_Asian] + [20-30_Caucasian]+ [20-30_Hispanic]+ [31-40_African-American]+ [31-40_Asian]+ [31-40_Caucasian]+ [31-40_Hispanic]+[41-50_African-American]+ [41-50_Asian]+ [41-50_Caucasian]+ [41-50_Hispanic]) Total
FROM T
PIVOT( COUNT(age_range_race) FOR age_range_race
   IN(
      [20-30_African-American], 
      [20-30_Asian], 
      [20-30_Caucasian], 
      [20-30_Hispanic],
      [31-40_African-American], 
      [31-40_Asian], 
      [31-40_Caucasian], 
      [31-40_Hispanic],
      [41-50_African-American], 
      [41-50_Asian], 
      [41-50_Caucasian], 
      [41-50_Hispanic]
     )
) AS P
```

Comment: This is good, but I also need a total for columns in the bottom if possible, Thanks

Comment: Then you need to keep these result into temp table. After that, make is union script.. select 'Total','', sum([20-30_African-American]), etc

Comment: Can you provide an example? I am sorry I don't understand it fully. Thanks