# SQL Pivot and Total ROLLUP

Tags: sql-server, pivot-table, rollup

**Please help me understand how to implement the `ROLLUP` on this pivot table.**

I have been looking over several of the other written solutions to my requirement, but I seem to be missing something when I apply them to my situation.  SQL is not my strength, but I feel like I understand more each time I accomplish something.

Creating this pivot statement below was a little struggle since I need to work with dynamic fields to summarize the total for different `dID` depending on the `cID` that the report is running.

I am using a method to dynamically create the `NVARCHAR` that will represent the columns I am applying `SUM` to in the pivot table. I've attempted to use the `ROLLUP` function as part of the `GROUP BY` condition of the `SELECT` without success.

The general layout I would like is something like this below.  Additionally, I have a second pivot with the same `dID` from a different dataset that I would like to merge the Totals from both into a new table, and create a GrandTotal.  I imagine this would be best accomplished with a `UNION`

- dID, dName, qID's, dID_Total
- 1, A, 100-113, #
- 2, B, 100-113, #
- 3, C, 100-113, #
- 4, D, 100-113, #
- 5, E, 100-113, #

  ```
  DECLARE @sID int = 100
  DECLARE @cID int = 5        
  DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

  --Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column
  SELECT @ColumnName = ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',', '') + QUOTENAME(qID)
  FROM(SELECT qID FROM qTable WHERE cID = @cID) AS QuestionID

  DECLARE@ PivotTableSQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
  SET@ PivotTableSQL = N'
    SELECT 
      dID, dName, ' + @ColumnName + '
    FROM (
      SELECT dID, dName, qID, weighted AS     [score]
      FROM sourceTable
      WHERE sID = ' + CAST(@sID AS nvarchar(8)) + ' AND cID = ' + CAST(@cID AS nvarchar(8)) + '
    ) AS PivotData
    PIVOT (
      SUM(score)
      FOR [qID] IN (
        ' + @ColumnName + '
      )
    ) AS PivotTable
    GROUP BY
      dID, dName,' + @ColumnName
  EXECUTE(@PivotTableSQL)
  ```

Comment: Please use the `N'prefix'` on all Unicode strings, consider [using `sp_executesql` for potentially better plan reuse](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/09/17/bad-habits-to-kick-using-exec-instead-of-sp-executesql.aspx), and also [be very careful about declaring things like `nvarchar` without length](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx).

Comment: I did see the N'prefix' on other examples, and honestly did not understand what that was there for, but I have put it back in the example.  I'll also add a length to nvarchar

Comment: [Stackoverflow Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17140559/using-pivot-table-with-column-and-row-totals-in-sql-server-2008), this is another question I have been using to try and resolve my question.