# Combine subtotals from two group by rollup queries in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, sql-server-2014

I have a nested unionized query that's structured like below which is essentially two of the query structures from this solution: [Using pivot table with column and row totals in sql server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17142530/14875035)

Is it possible to combine the two column subtotal rows between group by rollup queries?

```sql
SELECT
  [Line] = ISNULL(line_name, 'Total'),
  [A] = SUM([A]),
  [B] = SUM([B]),
  [C] = SUM([C]),
  Total = SUM([A]+[B]+[C])
FROM (
  SELECT sys_qty, line_name, stage_name
  FROM table1 a 
  INNER JOIN table2 b 
      ON a...=b...
  INNER JOIN table3 c 
      ON a...=c...
  WHERE line_name LIKE '%pattern1%'
) s1
PIVOT (
  COUNT(sys_qty)
  FOR stage_name IN ([A],[B],[C])
) p1
GROUP BY
  ROLLUP(line_name)
UNION ALL
SELECT
  [Line] = ISNULL(line_name, 'Total'),
  [A] = SUM([A]),
  [B] = SUM([B]),
  [C] = SUM([C]),
  Total = SUM([A]+[B]+[C])
FROM (
  SELECT sys_qty, line_name, stage_name
  FROM table1 a 
  INNER JOIN table2 b 
      ON a...=b...
  INNER JOIN table3 c 
      ON a...=c...
  INNER JOIN table4 d 
      ON b...=d...
  WHERE line_name LIKE '%pattern2%'
) s1
PIVOT (
  COUNT(sys_qty)
  FOR stage_name IN ([A],[B],[C])
) p2
GROUP BY
  ROLLUP(line_name)
;
```

Actual Results:

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| p1.row1 | a | b | c |
| p1.row2 | d | e | f |
| Stage Total | a+d | b+e | c+f |
| p2.row1 | g | h | i |
| Stage Total | g | h | i |

Desired Results:

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| p1.row1 | a | b | c |
| p1.row2 | d | e | f |
| p2.row1 | g | h | i |
| Stage Total | a+d+g | b+e+h | c+f+i |

---

**Solution**

Context: I'm trying to pivot the number of systems by stages (columns) and line (rows). One particular line needed an additional query involving an inner join with another table (table 4), but I still wanted to join all the lines together.

I made the following errors above:

```
- SELECT line_name, stage_name
+ SELECT sys_qty, line_name, stage_name

- COUNT(stage_name)
+ COUNT(sys_qty)
```

Solution:

```sql
SELECT
  [Line] = ISNULL(line_name, 'Total'),
  [A] = SUM([A]),
  [B] = SUM([B]),
  [C] = SUM([C]),
  Total = SUM([A]+[B]+[C])
FROM (
  SELECT sys_qty, line_name, stage_name
  FROM table1 a 
  INNER JOIN table2 b 
      ON a...=b...
  INNER JOIN table3 c 
      ON a...=c...
  WHERE line_name LIKE '%pattern1%'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT sys_qty, line_name, stage_name
  FROM table1 a 
  INNER JOIN table2 b 
      ON a...=b...
  INNER JOIN table3 c 
      ON a...=c...
  INNER JOIN table4 d 
      ON b...=d...
  WHERE line_name LIKE '%pattern2%'
) p1
PIVOT (
  COUNT(sys_qty)
  FOR stage_name IN ([A],[B],[C])
) pvt
GROUP BY
  ROLLUP(line_name)
;
```

Thank you Charlieface for the quick response as it was definitely the input I needed to get me out of that rabbit hole! I simply needed to restructure my query to union the raw data prior to pivoting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you want to `UNION ALL` *before* pivoting, in a derived/nested `SELECT`, then grouping and pivoting that.

Having said that, it's probably easier to use `COUNT(CASE` rather than `PIVOT` anyway

```sql
SELECT
  Line = CASE WHEN GROUPING(line_name) = 1 THEN 'Total' ELSE line_name END,  -- deals with nulls
  A = COUNT(CASE WHEN stage_name = 'A' THEN 1 END),
  B = COUNT(CASE WHEN stage_name = 'B' THEN 1 END),
  C = COUNT(CASE WHEN stage_name = 'C' THEN 1 END),
  Total = COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT line_name, stage_name
    FROM table1 a 
    INNER JOIN table2 b 
        ON a...=b...
    INNER JOIN table3 c 
        ON a...=c...
    WHERE line_name LIKE '%pattern1%'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT line_name, stage_name
    FROM table1 a 
    INNER JOIN table2 b 
        ON a...=b...
    INNER JOIN table3 c 
        ON a...=c...
    INNER JOIN table4 d 
        ON b...=d...
    WHERE line_name LIKE '%pattern2%'
) s

WHERE stage_name IN ('A', 'B', 'C')  -- do you need this also, to filter out other values?
        -- ... it might improve perf, also needed to get COUNT(*) to work correctly

GROUP BY
  ROLLUP(line_name)
;
```